# Consists of four

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The correct approach to this puzzle will lead you to two initials which in its entirety consists of 13 letters.

**What is this 13-letter answer?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Partial answer:** (EDIT: later completed into a full answer by [@Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)'s insightful [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106949/consists-of-four/106958#comment302251_106958))

Let's start with deciphering the elements.
The Xs obviously form

> Braille letters:
>   [image]

And at the top we have (most likely)

> **"FOLLOW THE CAPS"**, which can be read by tilting your head to the left and adding right halves to the letters.

Now, you might think the last of those three words should probably start with a "G" for the instructions to make more sense, and you may be right. However, I'm basing my guess on the result of the next step, which is a toughie: **Make sense of the grid.**

The image scaling artifacts make it entirely impossible to tell, but once I figured out the solution to this step (which seemed way too difficult), I noticed that OP has actually tried to give us a hint:

> The grid is supposed to be split into 2x2 squares. You can actually see the line width differences in the original sized image, if you squint hard enough.

Using that as a guide, (or doing it the hard way like I did: staring at the grid until it yielded something meaningful) we find the following words:

> APIA GIZA OSLO PERM
>  LYON NICE SUEZ PISA
>  BERN SUVA RIGA YORK

Out of these,

> Apia, Oslo, Bern, Suva and Riga are capital cities of the independent countries Samoa, Norway, Switzerland, Fiji, and Latvia, respectively.
>
>  The others are capitals of some sorts too, but the connections are too vague, so I removed the list from this bit.

These are kind of "all over the place", so let's skip the part where we'd plot their locations and see if that would form a pattern.

Instead, there are two likely clues we haven't used yet:

> * The location of the braille letters inside their squares
>  * The location of the capital cities on the grid

Both of these are easier to see with highlighting:

> [image]
>  (Interpreting as binary ascii, the rows spell "TTQQ@@")
>  [image]
>  (Interpreting as morse code, the rows spell out "II  TT"

And that's as far as I got. It's *way* past my bedtime, so feel free to continue from here if you want to.

---

**EDITED** in the morning:

In the comments, OP gave away that the letter placement inside the squares is not meaningful, and @Stiv actually solved the other part for the **final answer** of

> **United Kingdom**

which comes from interpreting

> the capital cities as Braille dots, which forms the letters ⠥⠨, ("u" and "k"), which we then convert into capital letters following the general theme of the puzzle, giving us the initials **UK**.

I guess I just *didn't see* that. (pa-dum-tsihh.)

Title also confirms that @Stiv got it right, as

> the UK (at least for now) consists of the countries of England, Wales, Scotland, and Northern Ireland.

Comment: rot13(Vs jr pbagvahr gnxvat gur tevq va gjb ol gjb puhaxf, gur zbefr pbqr npghnyyl fcryyf bhg VG, juvpu ner gjb vavgvnyf. Gur bayl guvegrra yrggre cuenfr gung VG tvirf (sebz Jvxvcrqvn) vf Vyyvabvf Gvzrf, juvpu zvtug or gur svany nafjre.) I would've made this a separate answer, but you did most of the work, so I figured I'd just add on :)

Comment: @Bass You're very very close. The left or right placement of the X's inside the small squares don't make any difference so don't let that confuse you. (I started making this puzzle without the "cross" inside the squares and then afterwards half-way decided to make a cross, so silly mistake, but doesnt make any difference anyways.)

Comment: You just have to re-think a little bit

Comment: Oh Bass you were SO CLOSE to the answer! All you need to do is rot13(hfr Oenvyyr ntnva! Jung lbh'ir tbg urer (pncf if aba-pncf) gura fcryyf 'HX' va Oenvyyr, juvpu zrnaf lbhe 13 yrggre nafjre zhfg or HAVGRQ XVATQBZ)

Comment: Looks good now, well done!

Comment: I thought the title was just in reference to rot13(gur gjb ol gjb tebhcvat bs gur Oenvyyr yrggref), but @Stiv's final answer makes a lot more sense than mine